# I am getting this error: stream_socket_sendto() ... no address was supplied

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin, laravel-6

I am getting this error

> stream_socket_sendto(): A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

When I try to upload an image of size 2.72 MB (2,857,082 bytes) although I tried to change:

```
memory_limit
upload_max_filesize 
post_max_size
```

to the max size look at this snapshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1mbV.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You set upload_max_filesize and post_max_size like "24M" for 24 megabytes and restart your server services again then check

I have one more suggestion: make sure that you have proper permissions to the folder with temporary uploads.

Comment: I did your first suggestion but nothing change.

Regarding your second sugguestoin, How to check the permissions to the folder with temporary uploads??

Comment: Check system temp folder search with %temp% with system search and check folder permission.

Comment: Is this what you meant?
it seems that the all users in my PC have a full control of the folder, isn't it?
[img]https://i.imgur.com/Y48jsAD.png[/img]